# Read datas from JSON array on HTML using JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have a JSON return by a PHP request. The result is:

```
{"serials":
      {"4":
          [{"serial":"15990"},{"serial":"16536"}],
      "16":
          [{"serial":"13841"}]
       }
}
```

Could you please explain me how to read each serial value to show them on html

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over serials using this code:

```
for (var key in json.serials) {
   for (var i=0; i<json.serials[key].length; ++i) {
       json.serials[key][i].serial;// invidual serial
   }
}
```

Comment: must have use document.write @jcubic ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var return_data = {"serials":
              {"4":
                  [{"serial":"15990"},{"serial":"16536"}],
              "16":
                  [{"serial":"13841"}]
               }
        };

        for (var index in return_data['serials']) {

            var data = return_data['serials'][index];

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                document.write('<p>' + data[i].serial + '</p>');

            };

        }
```